# bad tag error in feature file cucumber/eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber, gherkin

I try to add a tag in my feature file (using cucumber plugin within eclipse) but when I run my feature file it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" gherkin.TagExpression$BadTagException: Bad tag: "env" What am I doing wrong?
```

What I want is when I run the test, I want it to set the environment first before running the scenario:

Feature example:

```
Feature: Log into an account

@env
Scenario: Log Into Account With Correct Details
    Given User navigates to stackoverflow website
```

Class for Environment setup:

```
    @Before("env")
        public void setEnvironment() {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "xxx//chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            ActiveEnvironment = LivePortal;
            EnvironmentUsed.add(ActiveEnvironment); 
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add '@' for the Before annotation

```
@Before("@env")
public void setEnvironment() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure @ is added before your keyword and also if there are more than one then it should be like as follows-

```
tags="@Smoke-Login,@Smoke_Campaign,@Sanity-Campaign,@Smoke-Dashboard"
```

In case of one

```
tags="@Smoke-Login"
```